# Redirect user who isn't logged in before the page loads

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have question regarding security of a website which im building with googles firebase. For now it is very simple website with registration/login form and possibility to log in. When the user logs in, he is redirected to another page:

```
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
    if(firebaseUser){
      window.location = 'home.html';
    } else {
      console.log('not logged in');
    }
  });
```

Now as anyone can see the js file, you can tell where the user is going to be redirected without even having an account, so someone could just type in the website adress with `/home.html` at the end to bypass the login form. So in the `home.html` I added a script which will redirect user who isn't logged in back to the main page:

```
if(!firebaseUser){
  window.location = 'index.html';
}
```

Which works fine for now, the user gets to the page but is redirected almost instantly if he isn't logged in. But I imagined a situation where I would have some private information on my webpage and I wouldn't want anyone else to be able to login. Yet, if someone would disable javascript in browser settings and type the adress with `home.html` he could access the page and not get redirected.

**Question**

Is there some solution for that situation? To somehow check if the user is logged in and redirect him if he's not before he gains access to the websites files?

Comment: Store token into localStorage of browser when user is successfully logged in and check this(token) value each time when user try to access any page. If the value does not found into localStorage it means user is logged out. So, in this situation redirect user to login page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't enforce this client side. Anyone can just navigate to the logged in page. You have to enforce it on your backend or security rules. For example, let's say the logged in page displays the user's information, you will either be enforcing this via Firebase security rules (if you are using realtime database or Firestore, etc) or by sending the user's ID token to your server (if you are using your own backend database) and verifying it before returning content to be displayed. If someone is not logged in, they will get an error which you catch and redirect back to login page.

Another option, if you want to use session cookies and your own database is to try Firebase Auth's [session cookie management solution](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies).